# Generating an Avro Schema from a POJO containing a java.lang.BigDecimal does not work as expected

Tags: java, avro

Edit: [Here](https://github.com/filpano/avro-bigdecimal-issue) is a minimal example of this behaviour.

---

I have an issue with generating an Avro schema for an existing POJO. What I ultimately wish to do is read generic Avro records from a Kafka Topic and deserialize those back to my own model.

I am using `org.apache.avro:avro:1.11.0`.

The POJO looks similar to the following:

```java
public class TransactionEvent {

    private UUID transactionId;
    private BigDecimal total;
    
    // getter/constructor
}
```

The following simple code is used to generate an `.avsc` schema file from the above POJO:

```java
ReflectData rd = ReflectData.AllowNull.get();
rd.addLogicalTypeConversion(new Conversions.UUIDConversion());
return rd.getSchema(clazz);
```

Which yields the following `.avsc` schema definition:

```json
{
  "type": "record",
  "name": "TransactionEvent",
  "namespace": "com.acme",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "transactionId",
      "type": [
        "null",
        {
          "type": "string",
          "logicalType": "uuid"
        }
      ],
      "default": null
    },
    {
      "name": "total",
      "type": [
        "null",
        {
          "type": "string",
          "java-class": "java.math.BigDecimal"
        }
      ],
      "default": null
    }
  ]
}
```

Since there's no logical conversion, the generator generates the schema with a non-interchangeable definition (`"java-type"`). This much is clear. However, if I add a logical conversion:

```java
rd.addLogicalTypeConversion(new Conversions.DecimalConversion());
```

I get the error:

```
org.apache.avro.AvroRuntimeException: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: No recommended schema for decimal (scale is required)
```

I would have expected `Conversions.DecimalConversion()` to take in `scale`/`precision` parameters and then generate something like:

```json
{
  "type": "bytes",
  "logicalType": "decimal",
  "precision": 4,
  "scale": 2
}
```

which is the [recommended](https://avro.apache.org/docs/1.11.0/spec.html#Decimal) schema definition for decimal values, instead of throwing an exception that I can't do anything about.

I suppose I could add all my schemas by hand, but the effort required to do so for any non-trivial existing project looking to use Avro is... not little. To be frank, for such a widespread serialization mechanism as Avro, I've found the documentation to be quite lacking.

What am I doing wrong? I can probably just register my own conversion, but what's even the point of the available `DecimalConversion` then?

Comment: A minimal code example that exhibits the issue would be useful...

Comment: Sure. [Here](https://github.com/filpano/avro-bigdecimal-issue) is a minimal example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Digging a little deeper than I intended to, I suppose that the `ReflectData` API only uses the `LogicalType` and `Conversion` for maintainability purposes rather than dedicated interoperability. After registering my own classes, this seems to work somewhat. Unfortunately it does not differ very much from the standard schema as I've opted for strings for simplicity, but I suppose it was a worthwhile learning experience...

Full 'solution':

```java
    public Schema generateSchema(Class<?> clazz) { 
        ReflectData rd = ReflectData.AllowNull().get();
        rd.addLogicalTypeConversion(new BigDecimalConversion());
        return rd.getSchema(clazz);    
    }

    private static class BigDecimalConversion extends Conversion<BigDecimal> {

        public static final String BIG_DECIMAL = "arbitrary-precision-decimal";

        @Override
        public Class<BigDecimal> getConvertedType() {
            return BigDecimal.class;
        }

        @Override
        public String getLogicalTypeName() {
            return BIG_DECIMAL;
        }

        @Override
        public BigDecimal fromCharSequence(CharSequence value, Schema schema, LogicalType type) {
            return new BigDecimal((String) value);
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence toCharSequence(BigDecimal value, Schema schema, LogicalType type) {
            return value.toString();
        }

        @Override
        public Schema getRecommendedSchema() {
            BigDecimalLogicalType type = new BigDecimalLogicalType();
            return type.addToSchema(Schema.create(Schema.Type.STRING));
        }
    }


    private static class BigDecimalLogicalType extends LogicalType {

        public static final String BIG_DECIMAL = "arbitrary-precision-decimal";

        private BigDecimalLogicalType() {
            super(BIG_DECIMAL);
        }

        @Override
        public void validate(Schema schema) {
            if (schema.getType() != Schema.Type.STRING) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Arbitrary-precision decimal can only be used with an underlying string type");
            }
        }
    }
```

would generate like:

```json
{
  "type": "record",
  "name": "Transaction",
  "namespace": "com.acme",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "total",
      "type": [
        "null",
        {
          "type": "string",
          "logicalType": "arbitrary-precision-decimal"
        }
      ],
      "default": null
    }
  ]
}
```

from the POJO

```java
public class Transaction {

    private BigDecimal total;

    // getter/setter/constructor
}
```

which doesn't really help me much (I may as well leave the default behaviour so as to retain at least Java compatibility...), but there it is. The code at least could be extended somewhat easily to support `bytes` instead of `string`.

It's unfortunate that the `BigDecimal` support in the `ReflectData` API is not very fleshed out in Avro, especially seeing how many stream processing use-cases have to deal with transaction data and the accompanying arbitrary-precision decimals... :-(